# spark-ec2 --copy-aws-credentials not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

Using Spark 1.5, I've launched an EC2 cluster using the `spark-ec2` executable and the `--copy-aws-credentials` flag.  Upon logging into the master node, the `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are not set.  They are both set on the machine that launched the cluster.  Attempting to obtain a file through `sc.textFile("s3n://...)` in `spark-shell` on the master node throws an error asking for credentials.

**How can I launch the cluster with proper AWS credentials?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this exact same problem.

From looking at the spark-ec2 install scripts [1] I learned that the keys are copied to the `core-site.xml` files for both hdfs installations. You can check `~/ephemeral-hdfs/conf/core-site.xml` and `~/persistent-hdfs//conf/core-site.xml`. 
This allows you to put files in which ever of the two file systems you configured without supplying the AWS credentials. From Spark, you can then access the files in hdfs (i.e. `hdfs:///yourdata`).

If you want to access S3 directly from Spark, there are a number of options.

1. Put the same config in `~/spark/conf/core-site.xml` and `~/mapreduce/conf/core-site.xml`. You have to redo this every time you stop and start your cluster, which is annoying.
2. `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...` and `export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...` before you submit a Spark job (e.g. in the same script that submits your job)
3. Supply your credentials with your `s3n` url (`s3n://YourAccesKey:YourSecretAccessKey@yourbucket/yourdata`)

[1] https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2